# Vectorize function of fully constraint least squares

Tags: python, vectorization, least-squares

I have a fully constraint least square function as follow:

```
def FullContraintUnmix(end, y):
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    def loss(x):
        return np.sum(np.square((np.dot(x, end) - y)))

    cons = ({'type': 'eq',
         'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0})

    x0 = np.zeros(end.shape[0])
    res = minimize(loss, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons,
               bounds=[(0, np.inf) for i in range(end.shape[0])], options={'disp': True})
    return res.x
```

The function can derive b1, b2, b3 for following equation:

```
y = b1*a + b2*b + b3*c
```

where all b's sum to one and are positive: b1+b2+b3=1

For example, I have two numpy arrays x and y and run the function:

```
x=numpy.array([[1.09409701, 8.30291035, 7.55367133],
   [5.92192093, 6.70246926, 6.68206288],
   [7.7117292 , 1.26817188, 4.89139153]])
y=numpy.array([4.54848241, 9.40792865, 0.87531778])
z = FullContraintUnmix(x,y)
```

and I will get the b1, b2, b3 in z.

However, I would like to feed a list of y into the function with the same x to derive a set (b1, b2, b3) for each row in below list y2.

```
 y2 = nump.array([[4.54848241, 9.40792865, 0.87531778],
   [2.45441262, 9.36248009, 5.1424637 ],
   [3.93085281, 7.4927871 , 1.11965111]])

 vfunc = numpy.vectorize(FullContraintUnmix)
 z = vfunc(x, y2)
```

How do I vectorize the function without using loop?

I tried as above, but I get:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

How should I do it correctly?